# Json parser get value outside for doInBackground

Tags: android, json, list

I have a Json parser and `doInBackground` for loading more result. My json contain "name", "image" and, "nextpage" details. "nextpage" is a url link for parse again in `doInBackground` for more result.. How can I get "nextpage" link in to my doInBackground?

```
private String next = "first url";
private String url ="myurl
 public List<Item> getData(String url) {

        try {

            listArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");
            JSONObject page = jsono.getJSONObject("page");


            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    objItem = new Item();

                    next = page.getString("nextpage");
                    objItem.setNext(next);

                    objItem.setTitle(object.getString("name"));
                    objItem.setLink(object.getString("image"));


                    listArray.add(objItem);

             }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listArray;
    }



    @Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    int loadedItems = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
    if ((loadedItems == totalItemCount) && !isloading) {
        if (task != null && (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
            if (hasMore) {
                url = next;
                task = new MyTask();
                task.execute();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how and where you declared your async task. But if it is declared and called in an Activity you should add a constructor to your asynctask to take an url. Then call it like `new MyAsyncTask(next).execute();`. Before that you should make `String next = "first url";` a private variable of your Activity. In `getData()`change `String next = page.getString("nextpage");` to `next = page.getString("nextpage");`. Remove `String url = ///////////How getNext()???` from doInBackGround.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just pass it in the `varargs` that `doInBackground()` takes?  Then you would just call `new MyAsyncTask().execute(next);` and access it in `params[0]` inside  `doInBackground()`.